# ListView under a Button

Tags: android, listview

So I am trying to get a ListView to be populated underneath a button on the same layout. Basically when a ListView option is selected the button will respond differently to each selected option. The issue is it is getting a Force close and it seems to be a problem with populating the ListView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <ListView
    android:listSelector="#990000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    soundsList.add("one");
soundsList.add("two");
soundsList.add("three");



    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
             new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
             lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The Logcat readout is this:

```
08-23 10:21:23.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I have tried exactly what it says in the ArrayAdapter... (android.R.id.list. I've tried numerous other things including an extends ListActivity, but regardless of what I try I seem to get a similar Logcat response.

Is there a better way to pull off what I am trying to accomplish? I want the button above the ListView all on the same main.xml.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I had also tried this code. Currently commented out, but it was what I tried originally.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.list,LIST));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

LIST is a Strings array. The output on Logcat from the above code was the same as the previous.

Comment: The LogCat error describes how to fix itself and Nick provided a more detailed version of the answer. I suggest changing the `id` to Nick's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are either trying to implement a ListActivity or a ListFragment, which expects to find a listview instance with a specific name, hence the error.  Try changing the id of your listview from:

```
android:id="@+id/listview"
```

to:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

I know that you said that you already tried this, but given your code, it looks like its still wrong.  Once you change it can you post the new error message?  I realize according to your description that it's going to be a similar message, but even if the difference is slight it's probably still significant.

EDIT:

Another thing I just noticed - if you are indeed using ListActivity or FragmentActivity, get a ref to the ListView by calling `getListView() instead of`findViewById()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea I had given this one a shot and I just tried it again. Changed it to that and then tried with just changing the lv findViewById to (android.R.id.list) and compiled got the same error. Then changed the ArrayAdapters to (android.R.id.list) with the same as well. Here is the output on Logcat after second

Comment: 08-23 10:51:05.215: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(651): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using ListActivity or ListFragment?  It sure seems like it.

Comment: If so, see my additional note above about using getListView() instead of findViewById.

Comment: Posted code above that I used before that used getListView(). When I tried that code I had it set to extends ListActivity. Currently I am trying just extends Activity

Comment: Hmm...outside of those two classes, I can't think of anything that would throw the runtime exception you are seeing.

Comment: I found that I had accidently left it as extends ListActivity in the more recent tries. I changed it to Activity and now I'm getting a null pointer at lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); ... So I am trying to put in the getListView() as you recommend. How would you recommend restructuring the code taking out the findViewById and putting in the getListView()?

Comment: You can only use getListView() if you are extending ListActivity or ListFragment, otherwise you need to use findViewById().  Another possibility if its failing to find the view by id is that you are loading the wrong xml layout...can you confirm that the xml you posted is the actual and current contents of main.xml?

Comment: You should also probably step into your code with the debugger to see which object is null.  Sounds like you got your initial bug resolved at least :)

Comment: It is the correct layout. I seem to have it working now to an extent. It shows up as it should under the button and no force close. It extends Activity uses findViewById and uses this: ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
              new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, soundsList);
              lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: Yea now I just need to figure out why the selected one isn't triggering the sound when the button is pressed, but thats an issue in and of itself. Thank you for all your help.